# mahout - Necessary executable needed to integrate mahout in another application

Tags: java, mahout

I need to integrate mahout into a desktop application. Do I need only the executable/jar files? What about other directories (e.g lib) in the mahout folder?  Below are contents of the mahout extracted directory

```
bin           docs         mahout-core-0.7.jar          mahout-math-0.7.jar
buildtools    examples     mahout-core-0.7-job.jar      math
conf          integration  mahout-examples-0.7.jar      NOTICE.txt
core          lib         mahout-examples-0.7-job.jar  README.txt
distribution  LICENSE.txt  mahout-integration-0.7.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I figured that the `executable/jar` files in the root are all required. The lib directory has been packaged into `mahout-examples-0.7-job.jar`.